# DataGridCell style does not work when applied through the DataGridColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

The following template shows the `DataGridCell` content correctly, when it is specified as the `ControlTemplate` of a single `DataGridCell` (found after a Click event):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="gridCellTemplate">
  <Border BorderBrush="RoyalBlue"
          BorderThickness="2"
          CornerRadius="15">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"
                      Margin="2,2,2,2" />
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, if I use this template as the `ControlTemplate` in a style targeting the `DataGridCell` type, and use that style as the `CellStyle` of a `DataGridColumn`, the column cells' contents show up as `DataRowView`, meaning that the cells could not extract their proper contents from the matching element of the `ItemArray`.

Anyone knows how to set the Binding correctly for the `ContentPresenter`?

Comment: I just made some progress. Recalling some other answers on this site, I set the binding path to one of the column names in the DataTable currently showing in DataGrid. That did cause all the cells in the column show the elements in the named table column. In other words, I need to pass the column name to the template (but how?), or go through the hoops of dynamically creating a DataGridTemplateColumn (which I would like to avoid).